# can external users act as google workspace group owners?

Tags: google-workspace

I have a group in my google workspace that has mostly external users.
The groups control panel allows me to make some of these external users owners of the group.
However, I cannot figure out how a given external user, with ownership permissions, actually administers the group.
If the external user / owner visits  https://groups.google.com/a/the-domain-name/g/the-group-name/ they just get a "content unavailable" message.
Also, the google workspace group for which they are an owner does not show up in the "my groups" list at groups.google.com.
Does anyone know if having external users do google workspace group administration is actually possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the Sharing settings on our Google Workspace account.

In the Admin Console go to:

1. "Apps"
2. "Google Workspace"
3. "Groups for Business"
4. "Sharing settings"

And then choose **"Public on the internet"** under the section
"Accessing groups from outside this organization".

Also make sure to enable **"Group owners can allow external members"**.

[See an example of how I set up our sharing settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6k6E.png)

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I did a test with my own Google Workspace and made my gmail.com account an owner of the group. The group appears in the list at groups.google.com and the external account has the same access as the GW user to manage all the group settings.